# layout_weight does not work in 2.3.7 android

Tags: android, formatting, textview

The code below trying to put green underline below text in textview. This does not work on 2.3.7 phone but it works on newer devices. We don't see green underline below text in older devices. Is layout_weight does not work on older devices ? Is there any other trick to achieve the same ?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="#F21861"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="off"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#454545" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/underline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="#00a950"
                android:contentDescription="@null" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just curious what are you trying to achieve by `android:layout_height="2dp"` in the `ImageView`? Thickness? What happens if you make that 0 ?

Comment: Oh Sorry..It should be set to 0dp so that layout_weight works. I want to have text "top" and green underline below that text. It does not work on 2.3.7 phone. If I put layout_height as 2dp or something, then I can see underline otherwise not. I have updated code above.

Comment: If you don't want to use ImageVIew, you can still underline the text in `TextView` without the ImageView. But the color of underline would be black. I don't know how to change color. `textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() |   Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);`

Comment: I need to have green and grey underline depending if its selected or not. The colour of text change accordingly as well. Thanks

Comment: ok understood. Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238298/android-change-underline-color-from-an-edittext-dynamically ? Similar thing for EditText. Your approach seems easier and straighforward though.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Quick fix is to set height of LinearLayout to fixed size e.g 25dp and then set height of Textview to 22dp and height of ImageView to 3dp or simply remove ImageView and set background of LinearLayout to green with 25dp and Textview height to 22dp.. The link you provided is better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Soubhit Puri is better way of doing it.
[Android, change underline Color from an EditText dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238298/android-change-underline-color-from-an-edittext-dynamically)

Quick fix is to set height of LinearLayout to fixed size e.g 25dp and then set height of Textview to 22dp and height of ImageView to 3dp.

Or as per code below, simply remove ImageView and set background of LinearLayout to green with 25dp and Textview height to 22dp.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="#00a950" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="off"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#454545" />
    </LinearLayout>
```