# how to give underline color different and textcolor different to a Textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying this but it does not work for me

```
 Paint p = new Paint();
 p.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.getContext(),android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
 textView.setPaintFlags(p.getColor());
 textView.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: [Changing the underline color of TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716673/changing-the-underline-color-of-textview)

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
p.setflags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
textView.setPaintFlags(p.getFlags());
```

for more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245147/how-to-under-line-a-textview-text-and-change-the-color-of-the-underline) question.

Comment: it does not work it does'nt give me red underline

Answer (score 0):

```
edittext.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: it givies me crash

Comment: then i should only work in edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Create a under_line.xml file into drawable folder then set your textview background like this android:background="@drawable/under_line"

> add this xml in your drawable folder uder_line.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:bottom="-15dp">
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="0.5"
        android:pivotY="0.5"
        android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item></layer-list>
```

Then set your layout text view background like this

> android:background="@drawable/under_line"