# Edit color of underline in Edittext Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to change color of underline in Edittext and i follow some tutorials to do this.

I create this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

            <padding android:bottom="2dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

But i only do the underline not all rectangle, similiar as default line but white inside of blue and solid background transpartet.

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238298/android-change-underline-color-from-an-edittext-dynamically

Answer (score 5):

You can change it programatically too:

```
public static void changeEditTextUnderlineColor(EditText editText) {
    int color = Color.parse("#[putColorHere]")
    Drawable drawable = editText.getBackground();
    drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        editText.setBackground(drawable);
    } else {
        editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also create statelist drawables and put it there

Comment: how to change color of text selection pointer programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

you can change Edit color Underline in **EditText** specifying it in styles.xml. In your app theme **styles.xml** add the following.

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_text_color</item>
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!